# VS 2012 template errors

Tags: c++, string, templates, marshalling, visual-studio-2012

I've been using   [this code](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/mono-dotnet/cxx-cli-string-marshaling/) to marshal strings in C++/CLI for a while now. Recently I've updated to VS 2012 RC to try it out. I really liked the simple design, but none of my projects containing clix.h could be compiled. It worked great in 2010... What could be the problem? Thank you for your answers!

Here is compiler output:

1. Warning C4346:
       'clix::detail::IsManagedString::Result'dependent name is
       not a type.
2. Error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
3. Error C2059: syntax error : '<'
4. Error C2039: 'Result' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
5. Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

The code block errors are in:

```
typename detail::Select<detail::IsManagedString<SourceType>::Result>::Type<
typename detail::StringTypeSelecter<encoding>::Type,
System::String ^>::Result marshalString(SourceType string) {
// Pass on the call to our nifty template routines
return detail::StringMarshaler<
  detail::IsManagedString<SourceType>::Result ? detail::CxxFromNet : detail::NetFromCxx
>::marshal<encoding, SourceType>(string);
}
```

An example, source file:

```
#include "clix.h"
int main()
{
}
```

Clix header file can be found on this [link](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/mono-dotnet/cxx-cli-string-marshaling/).

Comment: Most likely you are missing typename keywoard someplace. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsx7wabs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: please add a minimal, compiling example that displays the problem

Comment: [Here's](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2267124/Template%20problem.rar) a simple project which reproduces the problem in vs 2012.
Please note i don't know if one will be able to reproduce it in vs 2010.

Comment: @rhalbersma Should rather be "a minimal, non-compiling example" in this case. :)

Comment: @Zylius Extract only the important part. I doubt anyone will be downloading projects and reading almost 200 lines of code just to answer your question.

Comment: I've taken from the project all that's needed and updated the question. Please note that clix.h is in the link, since it's pretty long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have just posted the issue on my blog, it's not abandoned or anything :)

I happen to have Visual Studio 2012 RC installed and fixed the issue. You can find a new version of the clix header at the location you linked.

Background: it appears Microsofts new compiler is a bit picky regarding typedefs in nested templates whose parent templates are specialized on integer types. In any case, I found a method that works in both Visual C++ 2010 and Visual C++ 2012 RC.

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping it updated. It's a great code!